# PHP fetch_array/sql without sorting values

Tags: php, sql

SQL:

```
SELECT question,alt_1,alt_2,alt_3,alt_4 FROM questions WHERE id IN ('12','2','32','23')
```

PHP:

```
while ($questions = mysql_fetch_array($game)){
    echo "$questions[question]";
}
```

I want the rows to be printed in the order the values are sent to sql: 12 - 2 - 32 - 23.

But fetch_array/sql(?) seems to sort the values so the order becomes the following: 2 - 12 - 23 - 32 (starts with the lowest number..)

Is there any way to stop the array from being sorted by numbers!?

Comment: I think for your case UNION is the solution, because 12-2-32-23 are not relational (not logical to conclude any order by)

Comment: Solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332434/mysql-order-by-in

Comment: Possible duplicate: [MySQL - ORDER BY values within IN()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/958627/1456376)

Comment: Thanks guys, the FILED function solved it.

Comment: @user1671375: Please do consider _not_ using the `mysql_*` extension anymore. It's being deprecated, because it's hopelessly out-dated. Use either the `mysqli_*` extension (`i` is for _improved_), or the more commonly used `PDO` extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT question,alt_1,alt_2,alt_3,alt_4 
FROM questions 
WHERE id IN ('12','2','32','23') 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '12,2,32,23')
```

Note **FIND_IN_SET(id, '12,2,32,23')** 12,2 without space

```
FIND_IN_SET(field, 'val1,val2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try yhis,
   " ORDER BY FIELD(id'12','2','32','23')"

```
          SQL: "SELECT question,alt_1,alt_2,alt_3,alt_4 FROM questions WHERE id IN 
          ('12','2','32','23') ORDER BY FIELD(id'12','2','32','23')"

           while($questions = mysql_fetch_array($game)){
           echo "$questions[question]";
       }
```