# Last Visited Products - Order by reverse product id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cookies

I handle last visited products on a cookie array. Assume it is called **visited_product**.

When a user visit a product i push product id to `$_COOKIE["visited_product"]`. Then I explode this array by "-" character.

Then I reach to db for product info with these ids

Example:

```
$_COOKIE["visited_products"] =  "12-45-67-89-3-6-9"
```

and my final array is `= {9,6,3,89,67,45,12}` // as you can see I reversed array for descending time order.

**When I request to mysql with this array it returs products in ascending order or descending order by `product_id`. How can I return product info like array's order?**

I don't want to add time value to cookie. It is possible with this structure?

my mysql query like:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = 9 OR product_id = 6 OR ...
```

Comment: see `ORDER BY FIELD()`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332434/mysql-order-by-in

Comment: @MichalVrchota thanks. if you write answer i will accept it