# I need this logic to be in one query in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need to make this logic in one query.

can anyone help please.

```
$ids = array('54bcf40b-9c78-4e08-a331-01bc5ab9b466', null, null, null, '54bb94bc-f5c0-4512-a593-01985ab9b466');

foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    $managers = $this->AccountManager->findByPropertyId($id);
    if (count($managers) > 0) 
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: You should put a little more information on what you want to achieve. All I can assume here is that you want to get the first id that has managers attached to it? If so, use inner join of both tables and get the first record id.

Comment: it's just only one table.
i need to get the managers for property_id in this array .
but if i got result from the first index of the array then stop the operation else check the next index.

Comment: You want to get the first result for any id? And I don't get the point of having three null ids in the hardcoded array.

Comment: no i need to get all results starting from the first index if i got results don't check the other indexes if i got nothing i need to check the next index

Comment: this array is from variables .. but the values it should be id or null.

Comment: take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332434/mysql-order-by-in

Comment: not what i want, and not even close

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions**

Comment: And [**filter out**](http://php.net/array_filter) the `null`s if necessary.